# Nexus 3 repository - Proxying an maven artifact from Hosted to Proxy repository

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

How to pxoxy an maven artifact from hosted repository to proxy repository in java. For Nexus 2 we used StorageTx, TempBlob classes etc which are not compatible with Nexus 3. So could someone pls suggest the wayforward

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to move things from Hosted to Proxy from within the code or are you trying to write your own Proxy code? Why not just use Maven2 Proxy is what I'm asking.